# How does Meteor handle the same subscription from multiple users?

Tags: mongodb, caching, meteor

Does Meteor read from MongoDB multiple times for the same subscription when it's made by multiple users? To illustrate, here's an example:

If you have the following publish function:

Server:

```
Meteor.publish('articles',function(keyword){
   return Articles.find({keyword:keyword});
});
```

And on the client you subscribe as follows:

Client:

```
Meteor.subscribe('articles', keyword);
```

When the first user subscribes (using the keyword: "meteor"), the data needs to be read from MongoDB. Then a second user subscribes to that same publish function using the same keyword. Does Meteor go to MongoDB again to fetch the same data for the second user or is it cached somewhere and served from cache? Is it possible to have it be served from cache and have meteor update the cache when changes are detected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does Meteor read from MongoDB multiple times for the same subscription when it's made by multiple users?

No, it uses query de-duplication. If multiple clients subscribe for the same dataset, then only one observer is used and they share a cache of the result set. This is true for both poll-and-diff observers and oplog-tailing observers. I'd recommend watching all of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_dzX_LEbZyI) where David Glasser explains how these algorithms work at a high level. Your specific question is addressed ~14 minutes in.